# Why would the reflections of the orthocentre lie on the circumcircle?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let ABC be a triangle which it not right-angled. Define a sequence of triangles $A_iB_iC_i$,with $i \geq  0$, as follows: $A_0B_0C_0$ is the triangle $ABC$; and, for $i \geq 0$, $A_{i+1}$, $B_{i+1}$, and $C_{i+1}$ are the
reflections of the orthocentre of triangle $A_iB_iC_i$ 
in the sides $B_iC_i$, $C_iA_i$, and $A_iB_i$
, respectively.
Assume that $\angle A_m = \angle A_n$ for some distinct natural numbers $m, n$. Prove that $\angle A = 60$.

> Why would the reflections of the orthocentre lie on the circumcircle?

this is the 5th question of [crmo](http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/uploads/crmo-2013-paper-3)

Comment: This question seems to be asking for an explanation of the initial observation in the solution given here: http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/uploads/crmo-2013-solutions-3

Answer (score 18):

Let $Q$ be the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, and let $Q^\prime$ be the reflection of $Q$ in side $\overline{BC}$.

[image]

Note that $\angle QCA$ and $\angle A$ are complements (as acute angles of a right triangle); likewise, $\angle QAC$ and $\angle C$ are complements. (Here, $\angle C$ refers the interior angle at vertex C of $\triangle ABC$; in other words, $\angle C = \angle BCA.$)

Then with the exterior angle theorem,
$$\angle Q^\prime = \angle Q^\prime QC = \angle QAC + \angle QCA = \left(\; 90^\circ - \angle C \;\right) + \left(\; 90^\circ - \angle A \;\right) = 180^\circ - \angle A - \angle C = \angle B$$

Since points $B$ and $Q^\prime$ subtend the same angle with segment $\overline{AC}$, they lie on the same circle through $A$ and $C$. (This is an aspect of the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem).) Thus, *the reflection of the orthocenter in a side of a triangle lies on the circumcircle of that triangle*.

Comment: In the given solution in your lnked page in the comment section of question can you please explain how they got $\angle QPA=\angle QCA$ and what is the intuition behind the induction step.i mean how they formed the inductive function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: $C$ and $Q'$...?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya: "Since $B$ and $Q'$ subtend the same angle ..." is  correct (if that's what you mean). However, I should have written $C$ instead of $B$ in "with segment $\overline{AB}$" and "the same circle through $A$ and $B$". I've made the corrections. Thanks.