# Radii of the circles circumscribing the triangles $BHC,CHA,AHB,ABC$ are all equal

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If $ H$ is the orthocenter of a triangle $ABC$;prove that the radii of the circles circumscribing the triangles $BHC,CHA,AHB,ABC$ are all equal.

Comment: Are you familiar with the extended law of sines? 
$$2R=\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\widehat{AHB}+\widehat{ACB}=\pi$, $AHB$ and $ABC$ have the same circumradius by the sine theorem, since they have $AB$ in common and $\sin\widehat{AHB}=\sin\widehat{ACB}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $H_A$, $H_B$, and $H_C$ be the reflections of $H$ about $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$, respectively.  Prove that $H_A$, $H_B$, and $H_C$ are on the circumscribed circle of $ABC$.

Comment: How will i prove that?I am confused,can you elaborate me,please?

Comment: What is the angle $\angle BH_AC=\angle BHC$, for instance?  The answer should be in terms of $\angle BAC$, $\angle CBA$, and $\angle ACB$.

Comment: Why are they equal,Sir?Is this a property of reflection in a line.And if they are equal,what how are they on the circumcircle of ABC?Sorry to bother you.

Comment: A reflection is an isometry, and every isometry preserves angles.  In this particular case, $B$ and $C$ are fixed points of the reflection about $BC$.  What is the image of the triangle $BHC$ under the reflection about $BC$?  Finally, I asked you to calculate the angle $\angle BHC$ to see why $\angle BH_AC$ is on the circumcircle of $ABC$.

Comment: See [this answer to the question "Why would the reflections of the orthocentre lie on the circumcircle?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/590777/409).