# Prove for a area relationship in a pedal triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Let $\triangle ABC$ an acute triangle and call $K,L, M$ the orthogonal projections of $A,C$ and $B$ on the opposing sides.
>
> Prove: $A_{\triangle KLM} = 2 A_{\triangle ABC}\cdot \cos \hat A \cdot \cos \hat B \cdot \cos \hat C$.
>
> [image: Pedal triangle]

I have tried many approaches but I don't seem to get there. Working with $2A_{\triangle KLM} = |ML|\cdot |KM|\cdot \sin\hat M$ causes issues because I don't see any relationship between $\hat M$ and any other angle.

On the other hand simplyfing the RHS as $|AC|\cdot |CM|\sin \hat C\cos \hat A\cos \hat B$ doesn't seem to work either.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to tackle the problem?

**No full solutions** please.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2A_{\triangle KLM} = |ML|\cdot |KM|\cdot \sin \angle KML$?

Comment: Woops, problems, I'll get right on it ;)

Comment: Hint: If $A+B+C=180^\circ$, then $$1-2\cos A \cos B \cos C - \cos^2 A - \cos^2 B - \cos^2 C \;=\; 0$$

Comment: The accurate name of this triangle is **Orthic Triangle**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Draw circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. Extend $AM$ , $BK$ and $CL$ to meet circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $A'$ , $B'$ and $C'$, respectively. Then

- Try to find $\dfrac{A_{\triangle MKL}}{A_{\triangle A'B'C'}}$ **Hint:** try to show they are similar.
- Try to find $\dfrac{A_{\triangle A'B'C'}}{A_{\triangle ABC}}$ **Hint:** They are inscribed in same circle.

**Full Solution**

Since [reflections of orthocenter lies on circumcircle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589877/why-would-the-reflections-of-the-orthocentre-lie-on-the-circumcircle), we have : $HK=KB'$ and $HM=MA'$ so $KM$ is midsegemnt (midline) in triangle $\triangle HB'A'$ which means $KM = \frac{B'A'}{2}$. So we have: $$\frac{KM}{B'A'}=\frac{ML}{A'C'}=\frac{LK}{C'B'}=\frac{1}{2}$$ $\triangle MKL$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$ are similar and $\dfrac{A_{\triangle MKL}}{A_{\triangle A'B'C'}}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}$

$A_{\triangle A'B'C'} = \frac{1}{2}.A'B'.A'C'.\sin \angle A'$. Now if we use law of sines we get $$A_{\triangle A'B'C'} = \frac{1}{2}(2R)(2R)\sin \angle A'\sin \angle B'\sin \angle C'$$ So we have to find angles of $\triangle A'B'C'$. $$\angle A' = \angle B'A'A + \angle AA'C'= \angle ACC' + \angle ABB' = 180^\circ -\angle 2A$$ So $$A_{\triangle A'B'C'} =  \frac{1}{2}(2R)(2R)\sin \angle 2A \sin \angle 2B\sin \angle 2C$$ Similarly for $\triangle ABC$ we have $A_{\triangle ABC} = \frac{1}{2}(2R)(2R)\sin \angle A \sin \angle B \sin \angle C$ So we have $\dfrac{A_{\triangle A'B'C'}}{A_{\triangle ABC}}=8\cos\angle A \cos\angle B \cos\angle C$