# Concyclic points determined by a triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

Let $P$ be the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, and let $A'$ be the reflection of $A$ about $\overline{BC}$.  Show that $A'$, $B$, $C$, and $P$ are concyclic (i.e. lie on the same circle).

Maybe this is easy, and it definitely seems to be true based on empirical evidence, but can anyone supply a proof of this?  I am not an expert in Euclidean geometry, so my apologies if this is known/trivial!

Comment: Okay, so this is easily provable with analytic geometry (and a bit of patience), but is there a more elegant proof?

Comment: That's just a matter of angle chasing. Note that since $A'$ is the reflection, $\angle BCA'=\angle C$ and $\angle BPA'=\angle C$.

Comment: See also the question ["Why would the reflections of the orthocentre lie on the circumcircle?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/589877/409), and [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590777/409) for a particular configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the fact that a proof may depend on the picture. Well, let us consider first the "standard" picture. The orthocenter is $H$ below, so that the hand will not type against my will. A prime denotes a reflection w.r.t. the line $BC$. The points $A',B,C,H$ are concyclic if and only if their reflections $A''=A,B,C,H'$ are so. We have thus to show that $H'$ is on the circumcenter of $\Delta ABC$. In the "standard" picture:

[image: mse 4797794]

$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{BAH'} 
&= \widehat{HCB} &&\text{ their complement is $B$,}\\
&=\widehat{BCH'} \ ,&&\text{ so $A,B,C,H'$ concyclic.}
\end{aligned}
$$
What about other positions of the points?
In case $A$ is obtuse, then $A,H$ change their places in the figure, so we have the same problem with points to be concyclic in an other order.

In case $B$ is obtuse we have the following picture:

[image: mse 4797794]

and the same argument applies. Instead of the complement of $B$ we use the complement of $180^\circ-B$. (Or we use the correct angles in green, which are not the ones marked in green, but their "opposite versions", opposite in the sense of $x\to360^\circ -x$.)

In case $C$ is obtuse, switch $B$ and $C$ to go back to the previous case.